# Play Framework modern-web-template with Java (AngularJs + MongoDB)

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I want to make a simple quiz web app with Play Framework. So I follow up [this](https://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/modern-web-template) tutorial to get start with a simple application that uses Play Framework, AngularJS and MongoDB and is created by an activator template called modern-web-template.

Everything is ok and the example app works but it uses Scala. I really want to use Java. I have not found the similar template to Java neither a similar template nor tutorial.

I have found some good tutorials like [this](http://www.toptal.com/java/building-modern-web-applications-with-angularjs-and-play-framework) to start with Play using Java and even AngularJS, but I get so many errors because these tutorials are for old Play versions.

So I ask: is there a way to convert a Scala activator template to Java? Is it easy? Or, is there anything similar to [modern-web-template](https://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/modern-web-template) or some other way?

I even tried using Scala, but I feel like [this guy](http://img1.rnkr-static.com/user_node_img/50013/1000240987/870/baking-photo-u1.jpg).

I'm using the last PlayFramework version: 2.4.6.

Comment: Will probably do best if you think of angular and back end as completely separate entities. Angular has no server side dependencies since it runs completely in the browser. It doesn't know or care what language or framework is used on server. So think of back end as nothing more than a data api that also serves html templates

Comment: @charlietfl I understand, but to start I have to find a way to put everything together to start working with it all following examples.

Comment: but my point is you can follow any tutorial that allows you to serve json data from mongo ... and any angular tutorial that shows how to use `$http` to retrieve data and create views

Comment: @charlietfl So I should leave the angular aside for now and just get with PlayFramework and MongoDB?

Comment: that would be my suggestion then you aren't limiting yourself to searching for resources that combine the two since there is no direct dependency

Comment: Also might want to set up mock data in json files or a json generaator site and figure out angular at same time